# The precise meaning of "much the same" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> It requires the same treatment, and for **much the same** reason.

What is the precise meaning of "much the same" in the above sentence? Does it mean "pretty much the same", or "exactly the same", or ... ?

Comment: Alternatives to ***much*** in this context include ***largely, almost, nearly, essentially, practically,*** etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you add your comment as the answer I will upvote it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I looked through your answers on this form and don't see any that have negative ratings.

Comment: @Readin I have done so. I suggest that this recent comment exchange be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> It requires the same treatment, and for much the same reason.

means

> It requires the same treatment, and for **pretty** much the same reason.

However if the reason was exactly the same, the sentence would be the simpler

> It requires the same treatment, and for the same reason.

There are many other valid qualifiers too, as mentioned in the comment from @FumbleFingers.